# Не срабатывает win +=1. В чем может быть ошибка?

Tags: python

Ребят, не могу понять. Почему При выводе статистики значения переменных `win` и `lose` - остаются 0. Почему не работает `win += 1`, `lose + =1`

```
from random import randint

while True:
    print("""
        1 - Загадать и бросить монетку.
        2 - Статистика игр!
        3 - Выход
    """)
    choice = int(input("Введите что сделать: "))

    lose = 0
    win = 0
    if choice == 1:
        guess = int(input("Как вы думаете что выпадет (1 - орел, 0 - решка): "))
        randcoin = randint(0, 1)
        if guess == randcoin:
            if randcoin == 0:
                print("Урааа вы выиграли! Выпала: Решка!")
                win += 1
            elif randcoin == 1:
                print("Урааа вы выиграли! Выпал: Орёл!")
                win += 1
        elif guess != randcoin:
            if randcoin == 0:
                print("Увы, но вы проиграли! Выпала: Решка!")
                lose += 1
            elif randcoin == 1:
                print("Увы, но вы проиграли! Выпал: Орёл!")
                lose += 1
    elif choice == 2:
        print("Вы сыграли следующее количество игр: %d" % (win + lose))
        print("Из них вы проиграли: %d" % lose)
        print("Выиграли: %d" % win)

    elif choice == 3:
        print("Всего вам доброго!!! Спасибо за игру!")
        break
```

Comment: Вы их обнуляете в цикле, вынесите обнуление за цикл.

Comment: Спасибо! А если допустим, мы можем выйти по комманде из цикла (игры) и потом запустить снова. Чтобы в новой игре были новые данные. То каким образом это реализовывается? Натолкните на мысль)

Comment: можно оформить весь этот код как отдельную функцию. при каждом её вызове будут новые данные.

Comment: Спасибо, Эдуард! Обернул еще в отдельный цикл. Но с функцией тоже хорошая идея, лаконичней! Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю, что вам надо вынести обнуление переменных ЗА цикл, примерно вот так:

```
from random import randint
win = 0
lose = 0
while True:
    # здесь основной код игры
```

Answer (score 1):

Из-за того что переменные обнуляются в цикле

```
from random import randint
lose = 0
win = 0
while True:
    print("""
        1 - Загадать и бросить монетку.
        2 - Статистика игр!
        3 - Выход
    """)
    choice = int(input("Введите что сделать: "))
```

if choice == 1:
        guess = int(input("Как вы думаете что выпадет (1 - орел, 0 - решка): "))
        randcoin = randint(0, 1)
        if guess == randcoin:
            if randcoin == 0:
                print("Урааа вы выиграли! Выпала: Решка!")
                win += 1
            elif randcoin == 1:
                print("Урааа вы выиграли! Выпал: Орёл!")
                win += 1
        elif guess != randcoin:
            if randcoin == 0:
                print("Увы, но вы проиграли! Выпала: Решка!")
                lose += 1
            elif randcoin == 1:
                print("Увы, но вы проиграли! Выпал: Орёл!")
                lose += 1
    elif choice == 2:
        print("Вы сыграли следующее количество игр: %d" % (win + lose))
        print("Из них вы проиграли: %d" % lose)
        print("Выиграли: %d" % win)

    elif choice == 3:
        print("Всего вам доброго!!! Спасибо за игру!")
        break

Comment: Весь нижний блок (начиная с if choice == 1) слез влево. Нужно поправить.

Comment: Эникейщик, я уже поправил это сообщение позавчера ;)